# Launch different Bootstrap modals on page load with different anchor tags

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I'm able to launch a Bootstrap modal when the page loads. But I'm wondering if it is possible to have multiple modals on a page, and to launch a different modal on page load, possibly by using various anchor tags with different name attributes? I'm sure there's probably another way to do this, I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: If by multiple modal you mean modal inside a modal [Check this](https://www.bootply.com/qRsvPSrcO5). Correct me if that's not the case.
Please post your code or your findings.

Comment: Interesting, although not quite what I had in mind. I'm thinking more along the lines of various anchor links to a page, each one triggering an different modal on load. For example, https://example.com#modal1, https://example.com#modal2, and https://example#modal3 would of course they would all take the user to the same page, but each anchor would trigger a different modal on load.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3Vykc/

Comment: @DhavalJardosh that's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks very much!